# How to generate swagger file to azure Java Functions without springboot

Tags: api, azure-functions, swagger, swagger-editor, azure-java-sdk

1. I have Azure Http trigger java Functions works for copy files from one container to another container, generate Sas token etc by using BlobServiceClient java class... These functions i created without using springboot now my requirement is I need to generate swagger Ui to this Functions please help me how to generate swagger file/ Ui for these functions
2. I tried swagger editor but swagger editor expecting Json input in my case i need to pass only one parameter

My api link:

http://functionapp name.net/api/functionname?file=filename

Please help me how to edit swagger Ui for above api in https://editor.swagger.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written the sample code for generating the SAS Token and copying the blob in Java Azure Functions without Spring Boot by following this MS [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable):

[image]

Then deployed to Azure Function App in Portal > Linked the APIM Service by adding this Http Trigger API to it > Click on Open API definition where you'll see the Swagger UI Json file:

[image]

You can modify the Open API file in any section according to your requirement:
[image]